# Creating xml file for reading interval value like hours, minutes, seconds from outside of application

Tags: .net, xml

I am working creating background service which will have some interval time to execute.

These values are depends on the requirement or amount of records in database. So I can't define hard coded it in my application. If I need to make any change then I need to recompile my code and generate new executable and release for testing team after that deploy/install it.

This is time taking process rather I want to use `xml` file and add required value there so that application will interval values from there.

How I have started creating `xml` file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parameters>
<interval
isMultipleHoursInADay="true"
isSignleHourInADay="false"
isMinutes="false"
isOnceInADay="false"
isSecond="false"

isMultipleHoursInADayVal="1AM,3PM,6PM"
isSignleHourInADayVal="2"
isMinutesVal="29"
isOnceInADayVal="12PM"
isSecondVal="40"
/>
</parameters>
```

As per my logic(this may be stupid) If above one `bool` option is `true` then I want to read that relevant value as a interval time. But I am not sure I am following the correct process of creating `xml` file

please suggest the most efficient way to do it? like certain way to define *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds*.

I these possible interval

```
EverySecond()
EveryFiveSeconds(
EveryTenSeconds()
EveryFifteenSeconds()
EveryThirtySeconds()
EverySeconds(3)
EveryMinute()
EveryFiveMinutes()
EveryTenMinutes()
EveryFifteenMinutes()
EveryThirtyMinutes()
Hourly()    
HourlyAt(12)
Daily() Run the task once a day at midnight
DailyAtHour(13) Run the task once a day at 1 p.m. UTC
DailyAt(13, 30) Run the task once a day at 1:30 p.m. UTC
Weekly()    Run the task once a week
Cron("* * * * *")   Run the task using a Cron expression use hours like 1,5,9

#Cron Expressions
Supported types of Cron expressions are:

* * * * * run every minute
00 13 * * * run at 1:00 pm daily
00 1,2,3 * * * run at 1:00 pm, 2:00 pm and 3:00 pm daily
00 1-3 * * * same as above
00 */2 * * * run every two hours on the hour
```

I have `C#` code to read the file, just I need to have file

```
public static List<string> GetFilterInterval(string path)
{
    List<string> filterProducts = new List<string>();
    var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fs);
    XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/interval");
    for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        filterProducts.Add(node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["name"].Value);
    }
    return filterProducts;
}
```

Comment: XML is not a programming language it is a data representation model.  you're going to have to provide more detail here.  thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I have modified my question. Please have a look on it. If not clear please ask me to edit it again.